# numbers behind % in printf and scanf

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I stumbled into this and I don't know what it does exactly

```
int i; 
for ( i = 1; i <= 20; i++ ) {
  printf( "%10d", (1+rand()%6) );

  if ( i % 5 == 0 ) {
    printf( "\n" );
  } 
}
```

Above is part of a program that tosses a dice for 20 times.

The thing i don't understand is this line:

```
printf( "%10d", (1+rand()%6) );
```

My problem is "%10d"

Is this a visual thing because outputs order of appearance change with it.

I know in float values it shows decimal point but what about in integers as int, also can anyone tell me the difference between this:

```
prinf("%.2f",value);
```

and this:

```
prinf("%6.2f",value);
```

They both print 1000.30, so what is 6 for?

Comment: Yes, %10d if 4 digit number is given remaining six places in the left filled with sapces

Comment: I've read the deitel book but it only explained it for floating integers

Comment: so 10 means output with 10 spaces?

Comment: 10 means total size where your number is printed, if number is less than 10 digits than remaining filled with spaces

Comment: Basically `%d` just prints the significant digits of the number ("1234"), `%10d` prints the number with 10 decimals using space for non significant digits ( "      1234") and `%010d` prints the number with 10 decimals, using `0` for non significant digits ("0000001234").

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"%10d"` means to pad with spaces on the left, as needed, so decimal output is at least 10 *characters*.